# How to bind a function after another in a same variable in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, trace

Someone already linked the func1 with the variable and I want to link my func2 after but when I use .trace() method, my func2 is executed first. Is there a simple way to say "execute yourself in this position in the list of functions that will be executed ?".

```
from tkinter import *

def func1():
    print("1")

def func2():
    print("2")

app = Tk()
var = StringVar()
e = Entry(app, textvariable=var)
e.pack()
var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: func1())
var.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: func2())
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is no way to control the order in which `trace` functions are invoked, other than changing the order in which they were created.

Comment: Then just interchange the lines? It might be because python reads the code from top to bottom and the last trace function given then is `func2()`, just a guess

Comment: Bad luck so... thanks for the information. @CoolCloud  You understand the right behavior but I can't link my function between the creation of the Stringvar and the func1 link (this is just a MVP, my code is more complex and I don't want to make it complicated). I was wondering if there was something like a var_func_list where you can add/delete functions and maybe insert in some position.

Comment: I dont think there is, try googling?

Comment: You can create your own function list, see [example](https://pastebin.com/isrhNCjq).